# Using a familiar to deliver a spell attack while both of us are under Sanctuary

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, touch-attacks, defense

Suppose both my familiar and myself have the *[sanctuary](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary)* spell on.

*Sanctuary* states that it ends when the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature.

The *[find familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)* spell lets me cast touch-ranged spells through my familiar.  I want to cast *inflict wounds* using my familiar; which of the two *sanctuary* spells will end?

Again, the end conditions are: The warded creature makes an attack (not possible for either of us), casts a spell that affects an enemy (not the familiar's spell, but mine), or deals damage to other creatures (again it's my spell, charged towards the target).

Comment: Hi Garry, welcome to the site!  Please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already.  You should also look at [this page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error), which explains the community standards for questions here.  Both a Community editor and I have made edits to your post to 'formalize' the writing a bit and hopefully improve the clarity for the reader.  You are welcome to roll back our changes or make specific edits if any of your meaning has been lost.

Answer (score 12):

#### Both castings of *sanctuary* end.

*Sanctuary* states:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

Since you are casting *inflict wounds* which goes on to affect an enemy, *sanctuary* ends for you. *Find familiar* states:

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll.

Now, your familiar delivers the spell as if it had cast it. *This indicates that the familiar is making the attack for inflict wounds*. If the familiar had cast *inflict wounds* it would deliver it by making an attack against the target, ergo it makes an attack when you cast the spell through the familiar. Therefore, *sanctuary* ends for the familiar as well.

---

It is worth mentioning that this does create an odd situation that might cause a DM to rule that *sanctuary* does not end for the caster of *inflict wounds*. If the familiar’s attack misses, one might argue that the *inflict wounds* spell did not affect the enemy creature, and so *sanctuary* would not end for the caster.  I wouldn’t rule this way, but there is room for it.

Comment: I believe the key is in the wording. For the spell caster, "casts a spell that affects an enemy" makes no mention of delivery system. Merely that the end result of the spell "affects an enemy". So casting inflict wounds will affect an enemy, therefore canceling _sanctuary _ on the spell caster. For the familiar, it falls under the "deals damage to another creature" umbrella. Regardless of how the damage was instigated, the familiar was responsible for "dealing damage". It just did it on behalf of the spell caster.